# SQL to Linq on conditional and column join

Tags: sql, linq

This sounds easy, but i would like to convert the below sql to linq.

```
  Select C.CompanyId, C.CompanyName, CompanyNumber, IsNull(UC.IsActive, 0) as IsActive
  From Company as C
  Left Join UserCompany UC on UC.CompanyId = C.CompanyId and UC.UserId = '2E34B10C-1BDB-4EF9-ADDF-4C5F949C19B1'  
  Order by C.CompanyNumber
```

Comment: Do you have respective entities for `Company` and `UserCompany`?

Comment: yes, i have both in my model

Comment: Kindly provide those details too

Comment: all thats really needed to know is that Company has CompanyId and UserCompany has UserId, CompanyId. The CompanyId is a foreign key in UserCompany.

Comment: Then help us visualize that by showing the code that represents that relationship in order to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this?  Obviously you'll need to add in your entity context's vs my Lists.

```
        var results = (
            from c in new List<Company>()
            join uc in (
                from x in new List<UserCompany>()
                where x.UserId == "2E34B10C-1BDB-4EF9-ADDF-4C5F949C19B1"
                select x
            ) on c.CompanyId equals uc.CompanyId into gj
            from uc in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
                c.CompanyId,
                c.CompanyName,
                c.CompanyNumber,
                uc.IsActive
            }
        ).ToList();
```